# How to execute a dynamic number of criteria in mongoose.find?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As an example, at any given runtime,

`Books = {
    CatSelect : ["SciFi", "Humor", "History"],
    MinPages : [300,50,500]
};`

If I manually write the query in the `find` function as below, it works as intended and finds the books with number of pages greater than the indicated amounts in indicated categories.

```
MyCollection.find({ $or: [ { Category: Books.CatSelect[0], Pages : { $gte: Books.MinPages[0] } }, { Category: Books.CatSelect[1], Pages : { $gte: Books.MinPages[1] } } ] }).execFind(function(err,result){
...
}
```

But the problem is I would not know how many of the categories will be selected, the above example is set `.find` example for 2 categories.

How to put a varying number of criteria dynamically into the `.find` function?

Naturally I can put all the criteria in a string, but query is not a string nor a JSON, so I'm kinda lost.

Comment: The only working solution I found for my problem above is to first find the minimum one (minpagesmin variable) of the pages entered for each category, then change my query to the following: { Category : { $in: Books.CatSelect }, , Pages : { $gte : minpagesmin } } I would then do a runtime check on the find result to further filter for those categories whose minpage variable is greater. Of course this is a bad bad solution, but the only one I could think of that could be a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build up your query object programmatically, based on the selections.  For example:

```
var selections = [0, 1];
var query = { $or: [] };
for (var i=0; i<selections.length; i++) {
  var selection = selections[i];
  query.$or.push({ 
    Category: Books.CatSelect[selection], 
    Pages: { $gte: Books.MinPages[selection] } 
  });
}
MyCollection.find(query).exec(function(err, result){
  //...
}
```