# Find data with no key value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I want to search for items in my database using mongoose `.find()` function.
In my router I have this code to get certain items from the url.
For example;

`mydomainname.com/market?type=1&name=hi&stats=123
   ...?type=123&name=&...`

```
var type = req.query.type;
var name= req.query.name;
var stats= req.query.stats;
Model.find({type: type, name: name, stats: stats})
                .exec(function(err, model){
                    if(err){
                        console.log("error")
                    }else{
                        res.render('*jade*', {models: JSON.stringify(model)})
                    }})
```

This works fine, but when there is no query value in the url(as seen above) the query value will be set to `''`. Which then sorts away every item I have on my database because there is none with exmaple `name = ''`;

I have search around but I have not find any help so if any would be able to give me tip I would be grateful!

Comment: If you ask if the value is empty or null? This answer explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16532000/3558900

Comment: Lets say I have 5 different querys and every of them can have no value. I can't see a method to use { $ne: null } where I don't use alot of if and else statements. And 2^5 is 32 different combination which makles alot of if and else statement. Can I somehow transfer { $ne: null } into a string object ?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995166/mongoose-optional-search-query-parameters

Comment: Then build your query programmatically. If you don't want a lot of if else, you can do a for with an array and ask if the value is empty. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15673923/3558900

Answer (score 0):

You could create your `find()` query object based on the value of the request query parameters. The following example checks for the `name` field if it has an empty string value, remove the property from the query and then use the final query object as your `find()` filter:

```
var q = req.query;
if (q.name === '') {
    delete q.name;
}

// carry out further checks 

Model.find(q)
     .exec(function(err, model){
        if(err){
            console.log("error");
        }else{
            res.render('*jade*', {models: JSON.stringify(model)});
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this



   var q = req.query;
    var data ={};
    if (q.name !=null) {
        data.name = q.name;
    }
    else if (q.type !=null){
        data.type = q.type;
    }
    else if (q.stats !=null){
       data.stats = q.stats;
    }
    else{
      data={};
    }
        Model.find(data)
             .exec(function(err, model){
                if(err){
                    console.log("error");
                }else{
                    res.render('*jade*', {models: JSON.stringify(model)});
                }
            })
```